# Hiding CPanel on production servers/Setup for production servers

Tags: git, cpanel, production

I intend on pushing my site to a production server. However, I rely on CPanel to do things like update some configuration files and check on my databases. 
Will there be any issue if someone comes across my cpanel by typing in www.site.com/cpanel?

What is the typical method of deploying sites from somewhere like a staging environment to a live environment? 
Currently I use deploybot to push it from my github repo but thats just my code. What about the server setup

Comment: "Will there be any issue if someone comes across my cpanel by typing in www.site.com/cpanel?" Only if your credentials are weak (easily guessed or brute-forced) or compromised some other way. For deploying, hosted sites like that tend to allow FTP or SFTP connections, and a deployment via that method should be fairly easily automate-able, if that's what you want. You might need extra tasks e.g. if you have database schema changes or whatever.

Comment: I see. I was wondering how do web applications get deployed or if there was a proper method at all.

Comment: Everything is dependent on your exact requirements / operating conditions / software components etc. There is no single "proper" way, you choose a method which suits your circumstances and covers all your needs. At the lowest level though, basically you have to copy and paste the code / compiled binaries (as appropriate) to the right place, apply any config changes, apply and database changes. It can all be done manually, so think through the steps and then work out how/if you want to automate each step.